# Wifi Adapter not working after installing NVIDIA graphics driver

Tags: networking, drivers

I'm using fresh install of gnome-ubuntu 16.04 and after installing the NVIDIA binary driver - version 361.42 from nvidia-361 from the additional drivers my wi-fi adapter stopped working. If i switch to the other driver -- Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau(open source), the adapter works fine.

Although the wi-fi adapter works fine with the other driver, it makes using my Wacom tablet unusable as it slows down to the point of being unusable.

These are my options as I see them: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkQCD.jpg

The wired connection works perfectly though.

Running 'lsusb' gives me:

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 1b1c:1b06 Corsair 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 056a:033b Wacom Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0b05:17cb ASUSTek Computer, Inc. Broadcom BCM20702A0 Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek SemiconductorCorp.RTL8188EUS      802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05e3:0745 Genesys Logic, Inc. Logilink CR0012
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1532:000e Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:082d Logitech, Inc. HD Pro Webcam C920
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1532:010e Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And running 'rfkill list all' only gives:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Thanks for the patience.